# Getting error at running my app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new at Android programming.I have just added some texts into my app just to learn it.But I couldnt run my app.It shows an error like this:

**Error:Execution failed for task** `:app:processDebugManifest`.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0] D:\MyAndroidProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage**

This was my first post.Sorry if I have done something wrong.I would be grateful if you could correct me.Thanks

Comment: Go to your AndroidManifest.xml file and change `minSdkVersion` to 9.

Comment: @AjayP.Prajapati i think the changes is in the build.gradle

Comment: yes, you can change it to both places. Manifest and gradle file. Then sync the project. it will be resolved

Answer (score 2):

The error explains the problem fairly clearly:

> ses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0]

The AppCompat v7 library has a minimum SDK version of 9. Thus you cannot support anything lower than 9 in your application.

Change your application's minSdkVersion to 9, and it will compile fine.

If you want to support API level 8 (you probably don't), then you either need to use an older version of AppCompat that supports it, or not use AppCompat at all.

Comment: How come it is named appcompat-v7 and it has minSDK at 9? Wasn't the suffix supposed to represent the minSDK version supported by the library?

Comment: @DanieleRicci the min SDK version for AppCompat was only changed in a very recent release. You are correct that the "v7" originally meant that it provided shims back to version 7. However, when the support library team decided to bump up the minimum SDK version, they left the naming in place for a variety of reasons, mostly to prevent breaking existing builds.

Comment: Yes thank you @Tanis.7x I recently became aware of that. I was just surprised when I saw the build error :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change minimum SDK version to 9 it will work properly.